# Opening links in existing Chromium window

Tags: kde, gtk, chromium

I'm using Kubuntu 10.04, with a few GTK apps (Pidgin, Evolution), and want to set Chromium as my default browser.
I've set the default browser in KDE's System Settings to chromium-browser, which works for KDE apps.

For GTK apps I set the same setting in Gnome Control Center, but instead of opening in my existing Chromium window, links from the apps open in a new window, with a error about not being able to access my profile.

How can I make GTK apps use open links in the existing window?

Edit:
I should also add that when the new Chromium window opens, the following error is displayed twice

> Your profile could not be opened correctly.
>
> Some features may be unavailable.  Please check that the profile exists and you have permission to read and write its contents.

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain why, but today I logged in and everything was working as expected. Sorry I can't give more useful information than that, but perhaps I just needed to do a hard reboot for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting in the chromium browser. I recently removed chromium and installed chrome so cant say the exact location.
Check "under the hood" may be there u find the option.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you tell me what the setting that you're thinking of is called?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
chmod -R 775 ~/.cache/chromium
chmod -R 775 ~/.config/chromium
```

This is what made everything to work and I am enjoying chromium even more than chrome stable!